# List not being read properly?

Tags: python, list

So im trying to programme a textbased pokemon game however i have encountered a problem while trying to have my programme find the pokemon, it seems like python is doing len(monster) letter by letter when i intend for it to be the length of the list.

list.txt file:
[Charizard,Charmeleon,Charmander,Venasaur,Ivysaur,Bulbasaur,Blastoise,Wartortle,Squirtle]

CODE:

```
file=open('list.txt','r')
monster=file.read()
file.close

for d in range(a):
    for i in range(len(monster)):
        if monster[i]==party[d]:
            f=f+1
            print('found',monster[i])
if f != a:
    print('there was a mistake at some point')
```

Comment: you seem to be thinking that python will red your text file and some how magically make it into a list. monster will just be a string you would need to convert it to a list if you want to act on it like a list

Comment: `python is doing len(monster) letter by letter when i intend for it to be the length of the list.` - If `monster` is a string and not a one-element list, then what do you expect? Python doesn't magically know that your file contents should be interpreted as a list, so it's a string `'[Charizard,Charmeleon...]'`.

Comment: As a side note, you may want to learn [how to properly use python's for loop](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements). And learn to [use the `with` statements for opening files](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) too. Actually, it looks like you would benefit from doing the whole official tutorial ;-)

Answer (score 0):

`file.read()` returns a string, so `for i in range(len(monster))` is itreating over all the chars in this string. Use `file.readlines()`

```
monster = file.readlines()
```

If every monster is in a new line, other with split the string by the delimiter

```
monster = file.read().split(',') # assuming "," is the delimiter
```

Comment: he might need to strip off the `[` and  `]` if they are in the line too as user seems to think that he can just write  python syntax for list in a file and reading it will create an actual list type object

Answer (score 0):

when you do : `monster=file.read()` at this moment monster is a string. you need to transform this string as a list.
Your list.txt is not evaluated as a list because it's come from a text file.
You can evaluate the string you receive with the `eval` built-in method like this:
 `monster_list = eval(monster)`
it will not working but your list.txt is incorrect to do that you need to change your list.txt in `['pikachu', 'pokemon']` you have to enquoted monster names.
But it's not recommended to use eval method for this kind of problem.
You should organize your file like that :

```
   pikachu
   pokemon
   ...
```

and read the file like that :

```
monster=file.read()
monster_list = monster.split('\n')
```